# Chrome Debugger is pausing on a deadline exceeded exception but I am only returning a message

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to user a very simple callable cloud function from a vue application to a firestore database using cloud functions. I cannot work out what is throwing the error and how to stop it.

I have reduced the code to the simplest I can to try and check I am terminating all functions correctly but the problem still occurs

The cloud function is:

```
exports.checkCode = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {msg: 'Hello'}
})
```

I call it with:

```
let chk = functions.httpsCallable('checkCode')
    chk().then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

as far as I can work out, this is about the simplest I can make it.

The function returns the object and displays it in the console absolutely fine but 60 seconds after the object appears chrome pauses on Promise rejection Error: deadline exceeded.

I cannot work out what was not cancelled and therefor leaves this promise to timeout...

I expect the results I am getting to terminate all and any processes related to the callable function, but i must be missing something?

Comment: FYI you can format lines of code by selecting all the lines and using the {} button in the editor.

Comment: Are you sure that error is even related to the callable?  Seems to me that if the function completed and the promise resolved, nothing else would happen related to it.

Comment: honestly, I am properly confused. The reason I related it to the callable is because it fails on this line of code `function failAfter(millis) {
    return new Promise(function (_, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(new HttpsErrorImpl('deadline-exceeded', 'deadline-exceeded'));
        }, millis);
    });
}` which is in the client SDK

Comment: I've traced the same error to the same API. Is there any possibility this is traceable to typescript compilation? Everything works apart from devtools jumping in and pausing on this timeout.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?